# Jackson XML parser fails when tags

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

The Jackson XML parser fails when there occurs attributes like this:

```
<some-float-value fr:relevance="true">99</some-float-value>
```

the error log look like this:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Float` out of START_OBJECT token
```

if I delete the Attribute, so the field look like this, it goes okay:

```
<some-float-value>99</some-float-value>
```

The class I want to parse to is like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Example {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "some-float-value")
    private Float someValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve by bumping from Jackson version 2.11.3 to 2.12.3

Answer (score 0):

Without the `fr` namespace the `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation would be enough to ignore the `relevance` attribute but unfortunately this is not case : if you want to get rid of namespaces in your xml file you can instruct your `XmlMapper` to ignore them passing a custom [`XmlFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html) as a constructor argument like below:

```
XMLInputFactory input = new WstxInputFactory();
input.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, Boolean.FALSE);
XmlMapper  mapper = new XmlMapper(new XmlFactory(input, new WstxOutputFactory()));
Example example = mapper.readValue(xml, Example.class);
```

You have also to modify your `Example` class using the `JacksonXmlRootElement` annotation and `JacksonXmlText` annotation like below:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "some-float-value")
public class Example {
    
    @JacksonXmlText
    private Float someValue;
}
```

Comment: It was bug Jackson version 2.11.3. It is solved in version 2.12.3

Comment: @Dasma,  thank you for the information, I didn't know about it.